# Map WebReponse to Model Class

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest

I have a service that is posting data to a URL and listening for the response.
This is the service call

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

HttpWebResponse response = null;
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, encode, true);

string strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

The string response that it's returning is

```
"{"TransactionConfirmationWrapedResult":"{\"ResultCode\":\"1\",\"ResultDesc\":\"Failed -\",\"ThirdPartyTransID\":\"\"}"}"
```

I would like to map this result to class like this;

```
    public class M2PDto
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "TransactionConfirmationWrapedResult")]
        public M2P2Dto WrapedResult { get; set; }
    }

    public class M2P2Dto
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "ResultCode")]
        public string ResultCode { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "ResultDesc")]
        public string ResultDesc { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "ThirdPartyTransID")]
        public string ThirdPartyTransID { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my deserializing  code

```
 M2PDto m2P = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<M2PDto>(strResponse);
```

I can't seem to figure out how to deserialize it, keeps failing by passing null to `m2P`

Comment: Fill your classes with sample data and then do a Serialize to see the jason results.  Then compare to the json you are receiving.  The classes are not compatible with  data you are getting.  Serializing will show the differences.

Comment: I can do that but the error remains, I don't know to map it from Response to the Model. It's urgent and a good answer would help

Comment: I think the response has an extra set of curly brackets around entire structure.  Try removing the outside curly brackets.  I'm really not a json expert.